# Need help in looping input in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

I have an input from which I am converting unix time and passing values based on 30 days condition, However the below script fails , Can anyone help here as I am new to groovy

Groovy:

```
def outputResult = """
{"view":
{"User0":
 [{"id":"0001"},
  {"id":"0002","lastLogin":1579783088323},
  {"id":"003"},
  {"id":"004","lastLogin":1641740132988}]
}
}
"""

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
def response = mapper.readValue(outputResult, Map.class)


 def thirtyDaysAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - (30*24*60*60*1000)
response['view']['User0'].findAll{ it['lastLogin'] && it['lastLogin'] < 
thirtyDaysAgo }.each{
loggerApi.info("Disabling user ${it['userName']} - lastLogin: ${(new 
Date(it['lastLogin']).toString())}")
userApi.changeUser(ChangeUserRequest.builder().id(string2Uuid(it['id'])).
enabled(false).build())
 }
```

Comment: Please indicate the exact problem or error you're seeing. The obvious problem in this script is that you're missing a closing curly brace `}` for your closure.

Comment: @ernest_k I have input from which I need to check if login date is more than 30 days I just need to disable them..

Comment: The question was about the problem. When you say *"the below script fails"*, what do you mean? Is the script raising an error? Is it not doing what you expect? It's important for everyone to target the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @ernest_k below is the error  "Unexpected character '&' (code 38) (expected a name start"

Comment: I think you should add the stack trace to the post, please.

Comment: @ernest_k   Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '&' (code 38) (expected a name start character)
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [31,52]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:666)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseFullName(StreamScanner.java:1944)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseEntityName(StreamScanner.java:2069)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveNonCharEntity(StreamScanner.java:1498)

Comment: Seems like that error is not being raised by the code you posted. So we really can't know.

Answer (score 0):

Something straight-forward:

```
import groovy.json.*

def outputResult = """
{"view":
{"User0":
 [{"id":"0001"},
  {"id":"0002","lastLogin":1579783088323},
  {"id":"003"},
  {"id":"004","lastLogin":1641740132988}]
}
}
"""

Map json = new JsonSlurper().parseText outputResult

long thirtyDaysAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - (30*24*60*60*1000)
 
json.view.User0.each{
  if( it.lastLogin && it.lastLogin < thirtyDaysAgo ){
    println "Disabling user $it.id -> ${new Date( it.lastLogin )}"
  }
}
```

would print

```
Disabling user 0002 -> Thu Jan 23 12:38:08 UTC 2020
Disabling user 004 -> Sun Jan 09 14:55:32 UTC 2022
```